# IIS URL Rewrite for Clean URLs

Tags: iis-7, configuration, url-rewriting

I am working on a site that uses IIS.  I have it working to remove extensions but then I was informed that the client was everything removed after the trailing slash.

I first thought this might not be possible with URL Rewrite, but then again I don't know much about IIS.

Basically if anyone browses the site and clicks on an interior page the url should stay the same, the top level domain.

`http://www.example.com` instead of `http://www.example.com/whatever`

this is what I have so far to remove the extension.

```
<rule name="Remove PHP Extension">
    <match url="(.*)\.php" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
<rule name="Remove PHP Extension">
    <match url=".*" negate="false" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)\.(.*)" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.php" />
</rule>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing it via IIS may be difficult since each link would actually have to navigate the user to the page in the first instance. And then you're stuck, unless you then redirect to the homepage and then perform a rewrite based upon the referrer - which is all a bit nuts.

Instead, you could use an javascript/jquery approach which may be better. Something like:

```
$('a').on('click', function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();

    $('body').load($(this).attr('href'));
})
```

This would take any anchor and override it ensuring th the content was loaded into the current page.

Admittedly, this is without any conditional checks for the `href` pointing to an page id etc. and also falls short when considering you may already have ajax calls in tht esite.

It also doesn't take into consideration forms submittals, but you could work this in.

Another problem with this is what would happen if someone navigated to a page directly.

A final approach would be to load the entire site into an Iframe. Nasty but apprpiate if that is the effect the client wants. You could have some javascript on each page that forced itself into an iframe if it wasn't already.

Whichever approach you take, your client can kiss goodbye to any search rankings. Which reminds me, don't forget to disallow all in your robots.txt

Comment: Awesome follow up @Digbyswift.  I really appreciate your help and thoroughness.  I did know about the iframe, which is a bad bad idea and the javascript but I was trying to get away with it without having to edit code and just some url rewriting. 
As you pointed out though it would prove fruitless anyway doing a rewrite because of the issues you mentioned in your first paragraph :)
I'm inheriting this so there is still some digging I need to do.  It appears to be fairly static with just some includes, doesn't appear to have any ajax or any javascript for that matter.

Comment: Thanks Josh, glad to help. I think in this case though an iframe isn't a bad solution if the client specifically doesn't want paths. The advantage is that if they change their mind, you just remove the iframe page and the javascript. Keep it simple.

Comment: Yea I suppose I would have to agree here, unfortunately lol.  Also, yes you are right about if they change their mind so it will help somewhat :)